# Get data by sending input to other website using simple dom parser

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, simpledom

How can I get response data by sending input value to some website through POST method by using Simple Dom Parser?
For eg, below is the URL and I want to post one data to this URL and I want response data as a output in my file.

```
$html_base = file_get_html('https://someurl.com/');
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Hi i think you looking for ajax. You can send Data to an URL and if your request succeed then you get your data

```
$.ajax({
  method: "POST",
  url: "some url",
  data: { name: "John", location: "Boston" }
})
  .done(function( msg ) {
    alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
  });
```